# How can I view binary .log files with application/octet-stream mime type?

Tags: mime-type, file-type

I have downloaded some log files from my server which I want to search for a specific string for debugging purposes. All of them have the .log extension.

The problem is that one file has the `plain text document (text/plain)` mime type while the other has the `Binary (application/octet-stream)` mime type.

I can open the `plain text document (text/plain)` mime type log file in a text editor as plain text but the other I can't since it's in binary.

How can I view the binary .log files with `application/octet-stream` mime type?

[image]

Comment: Go to Open With and select a text editor for the Binary.

Comment: @konrad That just displays a list of numbers and letters four at a time. Eg: 2042 4f41 0a32 3031 362d 3036 2d30 3320 \n
3035 3a33 333a 3332 2049 4e46 4f20 2050 \n
4453 4c50 6f73 7470 6169 644a 6f62 3a35 \n

Comment: Even if you change the mime type of the binary log file you still want be able to read the content with a text editor.

Comment: @konrad Fixed it, check answer :)

Comment: If you're referring to searching with `grep` specifically, and grep is simply misidentifying the files based on null bytes, then you can use the `-a` or `--binary-files=text` options to tell grep to treat them as text regardless. See the `File and Directory Selection` section of the grep manpage.

Comment: @steeldriver That works too. Can you convert it to an answer for a +1 from me. Ping me when done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19911) in [What makes grep consider a file to be binary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19907/what-makes-grep-consider-a-file-to-be-binary)

> If there is a NUL character anywhere in the file, grep will consider it as a binary file.
>
> There might a workaround like this `cat file | tr -d '\000' | yourgrep` to eliminate all null first, and then to search through file.

---

I first tried it with one file in a test directory:

```
parto@subroot:~/Desktop/test$ ls
info_pdslpostpaid.log-20160518
parto@subroot:~/Desktop/test$ cat info_pdslpostpaid.log-20160518 | tr -d '\000' > info_pdslpostpaid.log-20160518_edited
parto@subroot:~/Desktop/test$ ls
info_pdslpostpaid.log-20160518  info_pdslpostpaid.log-20160518_edited
parto@subroot:~/Desktop/test$
```

And the result, a `plain text document (text/plain)` text mime file.

[image]

Then since I am working with multiple files, I tried running the same command for multiple files in a directory:

```
parto@subroot:~/Desktop/test$ ls
info_pdslpostpaid.log-20160518  info_pdslpostpaid.log-20160520  info_pdslpostpaid.log-20160523  info_pdslpostpaid.log-20160525
parto@subroot:~/Desktop/test$ for i in * ; do cat "$i" | tr -d '\000' > "${i}_edited" ; done
parto@subroot:~/Desktop/test$ ls
info_pdslpostpaid.log-20160518         info_pdslpostpaid.log-20160520_edited  info_pdslpostpaid.log-20160525
info_pdslpostpaid.log-20160518_edited  info_pdslpostpaid.log-20160523         info_pdslpostpaid.log-20160525_edited
info_pdslpostpaid.log-20160520         info_pdslpostpaid.log-20160523_edited
parto@subroot:~/Desktop/test$
```

And awesome, all my log files are now in a readable format!! :)

Answer (score 2):

*Based on your own answer, you seem to be referring specifically to searching files using `grep`, rather than to changing a file's mime-type - see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).*

If `grep` is simply misidentifying the files based on null bytes, then you can use the `-a` or `--binary-files=text` options to tell grep to treat them as text regardless, as described in the manual pages:

```
-a, --text
       Process  a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to
       the --binary-files=text option.

--binary-files=TYPE
       If the first few bytes of a file indicate that the file contains
       binary  data, assume that the file is of type TYPE.  By default,
       TYPE is binary, and grep  normally  outputs  either  a  one-line
       message  saying  that  a  binary  file matches, or no message if
       there is no match.  If TYPE is without-match, grep assumes  that
       a  binary  file  does  not  match;  this is equivalent to the -I
       option.  If TYPE is text, grep processes a binary file as if  it
       were  text;  this is equivalent to the -a option.  Warning: grep
       --binary-files=text might output binary garbage, which can  have
       nasty  side  effects  if  the  output  is  a terminal and if the
       terminal driver interprets some of it as commands.
```

Comment: It wasn't necessarily just using grep, I just wanted to search the log files using whatever method. Maybe I should change the title and the question to reflect this.